# Видят ли краулеры автоматически генерируемые страницы?

Tags: seo

**Здравствуйте.** Возник такой вопрос, дай бог не забанят. Видят ли гугл, яндекс и проч. боты страницы и данные сгенерированные автоматически или извлеченные из баз дынных. Влияет ли это на поисковую оптимизацию?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Каждая веб-страница, которую вы видите в Интернете, статична. Тот факт, что эта веб-страница генерируется динамически на сервере, не имеет значения, потому что все браузер / искатель видит то, что создано и выдано для просмотра как статический html, css и javascript. Согласно этой ***[статье Вики](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping)***: "*Статические и динамические веб-страницы можно получить, отправив HTTP-запросы на удаленный веб-сервер, используя программирование сокетов*" и далее "*программы полноценного веб-браузера могут извлекать динамический контент, создаваемый клиентскими сценариями*". Однако динамические страницы не являются идеальными с точки зрения поисковой оптимизации - возможные проблемы:

- генерирование избыточного количества URL-линков с малым/низкого качества содержанием или с содержанием очень похожим на другие страницы сайта (дублирование контента)
- генерирование/использование URL-адреса, который делает его трудным для понимания Google структура сайта, например слишком длинный или же имеющий множество символов - ***[справка Гугл](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6080548)***
- чрезмерное количество изменений URL-адресов и отсутствие перенаправления для удаленных страниц
- динамические веб-страницы имеют медленную корость загрузки, и это плохо для мобильных пользователей - это примерно 50%-60% всего трафика

Comment: Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

серч боты проходятся по ссылкам на сайте, начиная с главной. Если где-либо там есть линк на вашу страницу с динамическим контентом, они будут его индексировать. По поводу влияния на поисковую оптимизацию - это не имеет значения. Главное здесь - кол-во ссылок от главной и SEО оптимизация самого контента.